# Is there a way of getting an odometer style count of messages that have passed through a queue

Tags: c#, msmq

We are trying to track our message queueing system (MSMQ). We have managed to put together some descent enough measurements of how many items are in the queue and how old the first item in the queue is. Is there any way of checking how any messages have passed through the queue in total to that we can do some MRTG-style throughput graphs?

Answer (score 3):

You can always access the [performance counters](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc736883%28WS.10%29.aspx) that MSMQ create at install; just go to performance services to have a list of what's acccessible. Then to hook up to the performance logs in C#, you can use some tutorials, like [this one](http://www.geekpedia.com/tutorial211_Using-Performance-Counters-in-Csharp.html)